# IIS 7 Anonymous authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have published my asp.net web site on IIS 7

I have used Anonymous authentication mode.

When i try to  browse files in "Report" sub directory, authentication required window Appears,

and when I change "Report" folder to another name user/password windows does not appear.

also there is no problem when i want to browse aspx files in root directory.

Comment: Do you have SQL also installed on the same server? Could have something to do with Reporting services installed on the machine.

Comment: Yes, Sql server with reporting service and IIS is installed on the same server, but "Reports" is mine and I dont think it is related to reporting service.